# Why i cant use '<' operation on my Search View

Tags: filter

### I want to create my filter to sort about 'Start Date' and 'End Date'

**For example**
i want to see the day that employee leave in 2013

- so i put

`<filter string="Year 2013" icon="terp-year" name="year 2013" domain="[('date_from','>','2013-01-01 00:00:00')]/>` 
 ***It's Work !***

- But when i put

`<filter string="Year 2013" icon="terp-year" name="year 2013" domain="[('date_from','>','2013-01-01 00:00:00'), ('date_to','<','2014-01-01 00:00:00')]/>` ***It's doesn't Work!***

i try many operation '>', '>=', '=', '!=' it's work too but when i use '<' it's doesn't

*Some one plz help me and thank you for you time to rend my word (sorry about my language :'|)*

Comment: instead of < try &lt;

Comment: It's work!!! thank you so much "Rudresh"
that mean &lt; is not in 2014 right ?

Comment: not undersrood i will answer now just mark it as answered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@iSS.f use `&lt;` instead of < because the HTML parser thinks it as the start of another HTML element. From there it starts rendering of new control so the error will occur.