# Remove attributes with regex. Just attribute value contains special character "<"

Tags: c#, regex

I want to remove title attributes in html. but just if the title value has '<' character.

**Text to clean:** `<a href="" title="bla bla bla" /><a href="" title=" bla bl<a bla" />`
**Output text:** `<a href="" title="bla bla bla" /><a href="" />`

As you can see second title removed from the text because title value contains < char.

pls help

Comment: use &lt; instead of <  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278451/why-i-cant-use-operation-on-my-search-view/20300551#20300551

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1)

Comment: @Jamiec I don't see anything wrong using regex for **that** specific example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do yourself a favour and use a HTML parser when working with HTML; for example [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Then tasks like this become as easy as:

```
var html = "<a href=\"\" title=\"bla bla bla\" /><a href=\"\" title=\" bla bl<a bla\" />";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

// select all nodes with title attribute
foreach (var element in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//@title"))
    // and remove it
    if (element.Attributes["title"].Value.Contains("<"))
        element.Attributes["title"].Remove();
```

Comment: You've forgot the "<"-check. So something like `if (element.Attributes["title"].Contains("<")){element.Attributes["title"].Remove();}` is needed.

Answer (score 3):

A suitable regular expression (in very simple terms) might be:

`title="[^"]*<[^"]*"`

This means `title="` followed by any number of characters that are NOT `"` then a `<` then any additional number of characters that are NOT `"` and finally a `"`

Then you can use it as follows: (note the quotes have been doubled in C# literal strings)

```
var test = @"<a href="""" title=""bla bla bla"" /><a href="""" title="" bla bl<a bla"" />";
var expression = @"title=""[^""]*<[^""]*""";
var rx = new Regex(expression);
var result = rx.Replace(test, "");
```

In my quick test this gives the desired result!